# jQuery setTimeout refresh when values are POSTed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Previously i was sending values through `GET` from `onChange` of select dropdown

```
<select name="addSel" id="addSel" onChange="addFunc(this.value);">
    <option></option> ....  <option></option>
</select>
```

and in my javascript

```
function addFunc(val)
{
   document.location = 'index.php?action=live&sub=add';
}
```

I could possibly refresh my HTML table with the condition `sub=add` and table contents dependant on `sub=add`

```
function refTbl()
{
    var pathtopage = window.location.href;
    $('#TableId').load(pathtopage + ' #TableId', function(){
        setTimeout(refTbl, 10000);
    });
}
```

Then i wrapped my select inside `<form>` to send values through `POST`

```
<form id="selForm" name="selForm" action="" method="POST">
  <select name="addSel" id="addSel" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option></option> ....  <option></option>
  </select>
</form>
```

My url remains `index.php?action=live` and cant able to refresh my table based on posted values

```
function refTbl()
{
    var pathtopage = 'index.php?action=live';
    $('#TableId').load(pathtopage + ' #TableId', function(){
         setTimeout(refTbl, 10000);
    });
}
```

This doesn't refresh my table based on values from POST through select onChange. 
how it is possible to refresh my HTML table using setTimeout based on POST values.

p.s - I dont want to use AJAX

Comment: where is function name in `onchange`

Comment: "p.s - I dont want to use AJAX" — So why are you using `load()`? That's an Ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) second optional parameter is `data`. Send your form data with this.

You have to [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form data.

```
function refTbl(e)
{
    // Prevent form reloading page
    e.preventDefault();
    var pathtopage = 'index.php?action=live';
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $('#TableId').load(pathtopage + ' #TableId', data, function(){
         setTimeout(refTbl, 10000);
    });
}
```

And call it on form submit

```
$("#selForm").submit(refTbl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. `$(this).serializeArray();` worked fine for me. I believe serialize() just creates query string. and serializeArray() creates actually an array.

Comment: Yeah, it creates query string what jQuery `.load()` accepts. According to docs: data must be a plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.